# Mysql - loop statement refer one column to the difference of two others

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I want to make column a(row 2) equal to column c (row 1) minus column b(row 1) for many rows.  The only way I can figure out how to do this so far is by creating a new column d that does c-b where row = 1.  The problem is I have to do this a lot of times and I know this isn't very efficient.

Thank you advance for any guidance on the best way to do this.

```
create table example (row int not null, a int not null, b int not null, c int not null);
insert into example (row,a,b,c) (1,2,5,20) (2,15,18,72) (3,54,57,228);
```

Comment: Are row numbers guaranteed to be sequential?

Comment: Please edit your mysql code to include the `VALUES` keyword and commas at the appropriate places

Answer (score 0):

If row numbers are sequential, you can use a self-join to relate row `n` to row `n+1`.

```
UPDATE example AS e1
JOIN example AS e2 ON e1.row = e2.row + 1
SET e1.a = e2.c - e2.b
```

Comment: Barmar, this is perfect.  Thank you!